# Android Toggle Button distorted view

Tags: android, togglebutton

I am building a app. At the moment I am just building a test UI so I can show off the functionality of the app. I ran across a problem where I want to have three ToggleButtons displayed in a horizontal fashion. So I did this using a Linear view. How ever the buttons are distorted looking. Here is a picture of the distortion:

[image: app layout]

```
private ToggleButton wifiTB;
private ToggleButton gpsTB;
private ToggleButton bluetoothTB;
```

Called in onCreate()

```
wifiTB = (ToggleButton)this.findViewById(R.id.WifiTB);
gpsTB = (ToggleButton)this.findViewById(R.id.GPSTB);
bluetoothTB = (ToggleButton)this.findViewById(R.id.bluetoothTB);
```

Layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/WifiTB" android:textOn="Wifi"
        android:textOff="Wifi" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/GPSTB" android:textOn="GPS" android:textOff="GPS"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/bluetoothTB"
        android:textOn="Bluetooth" android:textOff="Bluetooth"
        android:layout_weight="1"></ToggleButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note: 
- I tried removing a button for the linear view and replacing it instead below the close button.
- I tried placing it in a RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.
- Playing with the width and height of the layout/buttons.

Comment: Tried your code snippet and there was no problem with distortion. Is the problem still there if you try with another APK version in the emulator?

Comment: Yes it is. Tommorow I'll try it on my bosses Nexus S. But I appreciate you trying my code. Thanks mate.