# Distorted toggle button image

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

I have found several duplicate questions. I'm having exactly the same problem:

- [Android Studio | How do I scale the image in ToggleButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273986/android-studio-how-do-i-scale-the-image-in-togglebutton)
- [Android Toggle Button distorted view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583531/android-toggle-button-distorted-view)

However, their problems haven't been solved yet so I just want to ask a new question again. So the third one on the left is what the second is supposed to be.
The second button is a custom toggle button, the idea of which comes from here: [Android: Create a toggle button with image and no text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598255/android-create-a-toggle-button-with-image-and-no-text) 
And I place these buttons in a horizontal `LinearLayout`.

[image]

This is the xml of that part:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/post_button_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/post_content"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.807"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/post_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/post_divider2">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/post_comment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light_transparent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_comment"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="37dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="500dp" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
            style="@style/CollectToggle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_collect_toggle_bg"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/post_collect"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light_transparent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_collection"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="288dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="508dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/post_share"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light_transparent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="104dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="508dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: and what's that `@style/CollectToggle` ??

Comment: @MartinZeitler Actually I just change the name of the style in the 3rd link from toggleButton to CollectToggle